# Decay of the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I have read this post (and similar ones):

[Decay of the Fourier transform of a non-differentiable function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426119/decay-of-the-fourier-transform-of-a-non-differentiable-function)

and I have the following doubt: If

1. $f\in C^{n}(\mathbb{R})$
2. $f^{(n+1)}$ is piecewise and of bounded variation
3. All $f^{(k)}$ are integrable functions for $k=0, \ldots, n+1$

Can  I conclude that $\hat{f}(\omega)= o(\omega^{-n-2}), \:\omega \to + \infty.$ I just need a reference to find this precise or a similar statement.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just integrate by parts  $n+2$ times. Derivative of a function of bounded variation is a finite (signed) measure. Fourier transform of a measure is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your help.